# user create complex query and search over elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, frontend, backend

Is it possible user create complex query and clarify conditions for search from ui and search in elasticsearch? I know about boolean query in elastic search , but i need to implement my query that elach time user could send different condition for me like , < , > , != and ...

Comment: please remember to mark the answer as correct and let me know if I can help you on anything else

Comment: sure , but just a few things , In compare of sql query ,do you know witch one is faster , for complex query , and do know any kind of sample that explaine how could i implement query string on rail app?

Comment: It is faster as elasticsearch indexes the text optimized for search instead of doing %LIKE% quieres. My question would be why do you need the user to write things like > , < != instead of generating a UI that satisfies that needs

Comment: about the ruby implementation I think you should open a new question with more info about how are you currently connecting ES and ruby.

Comment: in project user could search with type of condition that it have no specific pattern so i have to use sql query but as i predict in few month my database have alot of information so use sql query is not very good idea , so i decide to use elk , and about your question it' s owner of project requirement

Comment: I answered your other question. By experience when the client start asking for "sql equivalents" is because it doesnt understand what kind of things you can do with Elasticsearch and you as his technical support should guide him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, there are two ways to accept operators from the user input :

- [simple_query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html)
- [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

**simple_query_string**

The simple_query_string query supports the following operators:

```
+ signifies AND operation
| signifies OR operation
- negates a single token
" wraps a number of tokens to signify a phrase for searching
* at the end of a term signifies a prefix query
( and ) signify precedence
~N after a word signifies edit distance (fuzziness)
~N after a phrase signifies slop amount
```

Example

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : {
        "query": "\"fried eggs\" +(eggplant | potato) -frittata",
        "fields": ["title^5", "body"],
        "default_operator": "and"
    }
  }
}
```

**query_string**

The query_string supports more complex syntax but it is not recommended to use it on search boxes because returns an error for any invalid syntax.

Example

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(new york city) OR (big apple)",
      "default_field": "content"
    }
  }
}
```