# how to implement query string on rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I have a rails project that I need to implement a search box in my project , I decide to use elastic search because performance speed of the query in comparison to SQL query it's important . In this project it's important that user could define type of condition like " < , > != , = " .I ask
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66421158/user-create-complex-query-and-search-over-elasticsearch?noredirect=1#comment117425681_66421158)
and someone told me that I could use query string to solve these issues. but I have no idea how could I implement in my project this type of query.

In my project, I use two elasticsearch gems, "elasticsearch-rails" and "elasticsearch-model" and follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/wolox/from-zero-to-hero-multimodel-autocompletion-search-with-elasticsearch-rails-3beff17fa8c6)
for implementation in my project but it's not useful for this issues.

could you please tell me how could I implement query string on the rails project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you run a query_string on RoR :

```
Article.search(query: { query_string: { query: "(new york city) OR (big apple)"} })
```

I just read you want to execute SQL queries on ES. That can be done out of the box using the [SQL API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-getting-started.html).

I found the implementation for elasticsearch-ruby here :

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/tree/master/elasticsearch-xpack

On this file exactly

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/blob/master/elasticsearch-xpack/lib/elasticsearch/xpack/api/actions/sql/query.rb

And this is the documentation about

https://rdoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-xpack/Elasticsearch%2FXPack%2FAPI%2FSQL%2FActions:query

Comment: This link are pefect but , as i read docs it could not use on rails app because it should configure on elk cloud